# MAC, ethernet id using python

Tags: python, ethernet, mac-address

How do you get correct MAC/Ethernet id of local network card using python?
Most of the article on Google/stackoverflow suggests to parse the result of ipconfig /all (windows) and ifconfig (Linux).
On windows (2x/xp/7) 'ipconfig /all' works fine but is this a fail safe method?
I am new to linux and I have no idea whether 'ifconfig' is the standard method to get MAC/Ethernet id.

I have to implement a license check method in a python application which is based on local MAC/Ethernet id.

There is a special case when you have a VPN or virtualization apps such as VirtualBox installed. In this case you'll get more then one MAC/Ethernet Ids. This is not going to be a problem if I have to use parsing method but I am not sure.

Cheers

Prashant

Comment: "I have to implement a license check method in a python application which is based on local MAC/Ethernet id" - You are aware that the MAC address is easily faked, and not secure on most systems?

Answer (score 6):

```
import sys
import os

def getMacAddress(): 
    if sys.platform == 'win32': 
        for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"): 
            if line.lstrip().startswith('Physical Address'): 
                mac = line.split(':')[1].strip().replace('-',':') 
                break 
    else: 
        for line in os.popen("/sbin/ifconfig"): 
            if line.find('Ether') > -1: 
                mac = line.split()[4] 
                break 
    return mac
```

Is a cross platform function that will return the answer for you.

Comment: I have seen this solution in an article. I am sure this would work on windows but on linux I don't have any idea that '/sbin/ifconfig' is a standard command and would work independent of any distro you use.

Comment: `ifconfig` will exist on nearly all linux systems, although you are right that this is a generally fragile solution.  Welcome to writing system specific code.. :-/  (This happens in any language, btw, not just Python).  Just sufficiently abstract this code (I would make it *much* more specific so that you are immediately made aware of platforms you didn't plan on), and use it.

Answer (score 4):

On linux, you can access hardware information through sysfs.

```
>>> ifname = 'eth0'
>>> print open('/sys/class/net/%s/address' % ifname).read()
78:e7:g1:84:b5:ed
```

This way you avoid the complications of shelling out to ifconfig, and parsing the output.

Comment: Except that requires `sysfs`, which is a lot more rare than `ifconfig`.

Comment: Yeah, but if you're like me, and develop almost exclusively for Linux, it's all you need :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used a socket based solution, works well on linux and I believe windows would be fine too

```
def getHwAddr(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    info = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927,  struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))
    return ''.join(['%02x:' % ord(char) for char in info[18:24]])[:-1]

getHwAddr("eth0")
```

[Original Source](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439094-get-the-ip-address-associated-with-a-network-inter/)

Comment: Does not work for Windows: there is no fcntl module. Thanks anyway.